How to run jupyterlab when asdf is installed?
Suppose that asdf is installed and we are using python 3.8.19. How to run "jupyter lab" as the regular command jupyter-lab notebook should be referenced in PATH and not working. On the other hand, it seems that adding specific path from asdf to PATH is not reasonable as we may have different python version in asdf and does not desire to add a new path per installed python version.
So, the question is how to run the jupyter-lab using python3 under asdf shimmer?

One of the easiest ways to run Jupyter Lab is calling it by Python command as follows:
$ python3 -m jupyterlab

As python3 is an extension here shimmed by asdf, it will run the same Jupyter lab version which is installed in the specified python3 environment.
